# Table setup in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am looking for the best way to setup my SQL tables in the following scenario.

I will do my best to explain my situation.

For instance, I have 10 tests, Test1, Test2, Test3, ...., Test10. They all use similar field but some tests will use different fields depending on the test.

Let's say Test1 uses Field1,Field2, Field3. Test2 uses Field1, Field2, Field4, Field5. I need to store the required field information into a table, but I also need to store what fields each tests use. I will be accessing this info using VB.net.

I am looking for the best way to set this up. It needs to be somewhat easy to maintain but also have pretty good performance.

My initial thought was to setup two tables. One table the would store each test results and one that would store the fields used for each test.
The one that would store each test results would have every possible column any of the tests could use. The table for which fields each test would use would also have all possible columns. In this instance, each row would be a test and each column would be which fields are used for that test. So, Test1 would have a 1 in Column1, Column2, and Column3. Test2 would have a 1 in Column1, Column2, Column4, and Column5. This would tell us what fields need to be used when selecting, Updating, or Inserting into our results table.

Hopefully that makes sense on what I am trying to accomplish. I am not sure if this is the best way to accomplish my requirements or not.

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tony

**UPDATE**
I just want to clarify that I am using MS SQL.

**UPDATE**
I also wanted to clarify that my field names aren't actually Field 1, Field2, etc. I am just using that to try and explain what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are 2 entirely different DBs.  You need a table to create the relationship between a Test and the Fields it uses.

Comment: Look at the answers found here; http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/how-to-handle-table-design-with-variable-columns . I've struggled with this multiple times. My recommendation is to go with a NoSql database such as MongoDB, or use a database such as MS-SQL or PostreSQL that supports a native XML data type that can be queried. In the later scenario, store your meta-data in fields and your object (test) in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for I believe, is a variable column table. Especially if you consider the long-term affects of adding more tests.

One thing for certain, the way NOT to solve the problem is to add a bunch of columns with generic names (field1, 2, 3 .... 40) and use them as you need in hopes that you never need 40. This makes for a design that is highly problematic to develop around and maintain.

A less horrible approach but still problematic is to make a table that pivots fields and makes them each their own row, and associates the two.

A better solution, using modern databases, is to store your objects (tests) in a no-schema type of way. In a relational database that supports it, you can use a native XML field (or json in some databases). In this scenario, you store the meta data about the object in regular fields and store the XML-serialized objects in the xml field. This way, your object can change as needed without a change to the database schema and you can continue to use meaningful names and data types.

It is important in the relational db scenario to choose a db that has a native xml or json datatype, vs. just using a varchar or blob. The reason is that a native type will include the ability to query the data in ways that are generally more performant than regex.

Of course, this what no-sql databases such as MongoDB are great at. I've had good success with both approaches. For simple solutions, I'll generally choose Mongo. For solutions in which I need a relational database anyway, I'll use MS-SQL and SQLXml.

SteveJ

Comment: Thanks for the answer SteveJ. I am using MS SQL for my setup. Do you have an example or two on what your setup would be?

Answer (score 0):

You need four tables. Tests and Fields have a many-to-many relationship, so you need these two tables plus a TestsFields junction table. Finally you need a results table with TestNumber, Fieldnumber and Result fields. This fits the information given in your question, though it's a little ambiguous. You might need to extend this schema to accomodate multiple testsessions/exams, or whatever - you've not given this context so I can't say.

EDIT:

For instance, lets take a car servicing app as an example.
(Unfortunately you've chosen 'Fields' for one of your tables, and I want to use 'fields' in what follows, so I've distinguished them by capitalisation) In this scenario, Tests table would have the fields TestID and Description, with values like 1, 'Pre-delivery Inspection', 2, '5000 mile service' etc and Fields table would have fieldID and Description, with values like 1, 'Check tyre pressure' , 2, 'Check Handbrake cable' etc.
Then the junction table TestsFields would just consist of the two primary keys.

In this scenario, you would also need another table or two to cover the individual cars, service appointments etc, but let's not get carried away!

The results table would include ServiceApptID,TestID, FieldID, and Result. Result could be free text, where the mechanic could record results, or another lookup to a set of canned responses - 1 'Adjusted', 2, 'Part Replaced' etc

Should be enough there to get the idea across.

Comment: Thanks for the answer peterG. Do you have an example on how this would be setup?

Comment: I've already described it as far as I can. Not sure what I can add without a lot more info about your application, or a more specific question.

Comment: Yeah, I mapped it out and I think I know what the setup is. I do have a question as for the different column types. For instance, if Field1 was an Integer and Field2 was a String, how would I setup the results table? Would I setup multiple Result columns for each possible column type? Or would I just setup one result column as a varchar and store all results to that one column?

Answer (score -1):

I think the better way is use custom char as separator for example `|` char
like this

`somthing|another field|another filed data`

when you want to read data split by `|`

and also you can save selected value by this scenario

`1|3|5|2|0|4|1|2`

you need only 2 string field to store question and answer :)

Comment: The problem with such an approach is that it makes it difficult to ask meaningful questions about the test results. You can't easily, for example, ask for a count of all of the nth test results with values between 3 and 6 that were run on Thursday.

Comment: @SteveJ I can not understand you could you explain more?

Comment: SQL is really good at ad-hoc queries if you have 1 value per field. For simplicity, if you have author and book title, it is really easy to ask SQL 'How many books were written by Dr. Suess?' Plus, you can index on Author, making the query fast. If you were to combine them ("Author | Book"), it is no longer easy to ask that same question - now you have to write custom filters - and you can no longer index on Author, and both have to be strings - (maybe test result is integer). You loose a lot of what SQL is good at when you combine values into a single field.

Comment: @SteveJ yes it is. Now I understand. This is simple solution for this question. it must be improved by question type

Comment: @SteveJ is correct. This answer is completely contrary to the principles of db normalisation.

Comment: @SteveJ But you can save data by coding it like 2:anwer1

Comment: @peterG by coding data search is available in simple string. what do you think?

Comment: No, cramming multiple data items into one field is just fighting the very basics of how relational databases work. Never do it.

Comment: @Sinoheh; I'll make this my last comment here, otherwise we should really move this to chat - but since it is an important concept.... In your example, how do you ask 'is the answer between 2 and 50e10?'. Now your simple string search isn't so simple - especially since strings sort differently than integers on some platforms. Also, how do you add an index by the question? (the answer is you can't). How do you do aggregation, not simple either? Yes, these can be overcome as well as a lot of bad design practices, but it adds way to much complication to an otherwise simple problem.

Comment: @SteveJ I use this method in huge data database. Its clear when read field and its good when you do not want to know any featured data from question and answers. In my project user make test with 2 to 10 radio button test dynamically. I save questions in one database field and all answer in another string field. All thing day need to find out true and false selection and client to check his result with real answer. everything is clear for both admin and client in database. its work great in my question and answer case. There is 10^6 records I don't want use many inner join. Many i/o ..